# Prevent Tomcat from starting up on application error

Tags: java, tomcat8

I have a problem with my tomcat: Right now on application startup I get some Liquibase Errors with stack traces.

So the tomcat correctly logs:

```
SEVERE: Error deploying deployment descriptor [/appl/tomcat/apps/myApp/apache-tomcat-8.5.66_vw/conf/Catalina/localhost/myApp.xml]
```

... which is correct.

**BUT:** Only a few lines later the tomcat logs the following line:

```
INFO: Server startup in 250469 ms
```

How can I prevent the tomcat from finishing up the startup process when a severe error occurs?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Out of interest, how would that help you?

Comment: When the aplication starts with a new version the first time, it executes liquibase scripts that change the database structure. We want to prevent that the tomcat starts when for example those scripts fail.
Also we are deploying automatically on many servers in a row over Bamboo and want to see immediately when one deployment fails. When the tomcat starts, bamboo will continue deploying the rest of the servers. That must not happen.

Comment: The simple remedy would be to have a script that executes the two tasks serially. If the first one (db) fails, the second (starting Tomcat) would not be run